# Add time slider for a stack of rasters

Tags: r, leaflet, r-raster, terra, r-leaflet

I'm looking for a **static HTML** solution (no Shiny) to incorporate a timeslider for raster data in a leaflet.

`leaflet.extras2::addTimeslider()` requires the `data` argument to be "a Simple Feature collection of type POINT or LINESTRING with a column of class Date or POSIXct."

How can we achieve for raster data what this function does for point and linestring data?

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras2)
library(sf)
library(geojsonsf)

data <- sf::st_as_sf(leaflet::atlStorms2005[1,])
data <- st_cast(data, "POINT")
data$time = as.POSIXct(
    seq.POSIXt(Sys.time() - 1000, Sys.time(), length.out = nrow(data)))

leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addTimeslider(data = data,
                  options = timesliderOptions(
                      position = "topright",
                      timeAttribute = "time",
                      range = TRUE)) %>%
    setView(-72, 22, 4)
```

[image]